# Getting no response from Dao class when i hit tha same url more than 4th times

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, session

I am hitting some Url link on web browser of my spring hibernate project
url working fine till the 4 continuosly hits but when i hitsame url 5th time

its not responding its showing only  processing.. and its not showing any exception

here is the code of my method that get called by the controller class

```
 public List<Object> getListForSingleColumn(String query){
     List<Object> ls_ob = new ArrayList<Object>();
     try {


     Session session = this.sessionFactory.openSession();
        /*Session session = this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();*/
         System.out.println("step--1 in getListForSingleColumn");
            Query q = session.createQuery(query);
            System.out.println("step--2 in getListForSingleColumn");
            ls_ob  = q.list();
            System.out.println("step--3 in getListForSingleColumn");
     } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception in getListForSingleColumn "+e);
        }
     System.out.println("returning in getListForSingleColumn");
            return ls_ob;
        }
```

> when i hit the same url 5th time then the output i got is like below:

```
step--1 in getListForSingleColumn
step--2 in getListForSingleColumn
Hibernate: select distinct wallpaper0_.cat as col_0_0_ from Wallpaper_s wallpaper0_

till the 4th time its working fine
```

> how can i analysis this problem... i dnt have too much knowledge of
>   hibernate and spring?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Obviously, you don't close a session. So your application stall, because of out of memory.

If you want to learn Hibernate, begin from a simple console application without DAO and Spring.

You don't notice `OutOfMemoryError`, because of it is an `Error` not an `Exception` that you catch. And you should output an exception this way

```
e.printStackTrace();
```

The most valid way is to use a logger

```
LOG.error("Exception in getListForSingleColumn", e);
```

Comment: But  it should have throw exception out of memory.. why it was not giving any exception ?

Comment: i removed session.close() and i wrote e.printStackTrace(); but still its not showing any exception

Comment: Actually  i have used @Transactional annotation on my service class method so  that might be the reason to not showing any exception?

Comment: @KunalBatra The reason is _`OutOfMemoryError` is an `Error` not an `Exception`_.

Comment: thanx for the reply :)